# Access vba: Creating Outlook Task/ If Null then

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been trying to have a button that will create a task on Outlook.
But I also need a code that will show a message box when one of the mandatory fields is empty instead of seeing an error message generated by Access itself.

Outlook tasks are being created successfully, but the NULL field (dueBY) is the problem when setting the reminder time.

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblActions")

Set outLookApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set OutlookTask = outLookApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

With OutlookTask
.Subject = "Action Due Date: " & Me.dueBy & " for Contract ID " & Me.contractID
.Body = "Due date for Action: < " & Me.actionNote & " > is " & Me.dueBy & "."
.ReminderSet = True
If Me.dueBy = "" Then
MsgBox "No set due date"
Else: OutlookTask.ReminderTime = Me.dueBy 
End If
.Save
End With

MsgBox "Action Task has been set in Outlook successfully."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have code in there checking `dueBy`, you just need an `Exit Sub` on the line after the message box.

Comment: Or better, move the `.Save` up into the `Else` block, get rid of that ugly instructions separator and have an actual `Else` block. And indent.